# Can GetTypeInfo ever return null?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I am rewriting some code (targeting .NET 4.5.2. currently) that uses reflection to compile for .NET Standard 1.4. I therefore need to use GetTypeInfo() on a Type at many places.

In order to handle the edge cases correctly, my question is, can GetTypeInfo() ever return null? The documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) is silent about this.

When I open a source of GetTypeInfo() from a standard .NET 4.5.2 project, I get:

```
public static class IntrospectionExtensions
{
    public static TypeInfo GetTypeInfo(this Type type){
        if(type == null){
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        }
        var rcType=(IReflectableType)type;
        if(rcType==null){
            return null;
        }else{
            return rcType.GetTypeInfo();
        }
    }   
}
```

That is still confusing. There is a code branch that returns null when '(IReflectableType)type' is null, but why? - the 'type' itself is checked against null before, and an exception is thrown when it is null, therefore I cannot see how 'rcType' can ever be null (mind you, this is not an 'as' operator, it is a straight typecast).

In a good tradition, the documentation on IReflectableType.GetTypeInfo (, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflectabletype.gettypeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx ) is also silent about the possibility of a null outcome.

A code that uses reflection needs to use GetTypeInfo at many places, and if a null results is allowed, it would therefore require to have a null check and a corresponding action at every such place. I have checked other people's code (including Microsoft's own example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ) and developers seem to be treating it as a null result was not possible. Is that correct?

Comment: Since `TypeInfo` is a [refactoring](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api/) of some of what was originally covered by `Type`, and `Object.GetType()` is never expected to return `null` (with good reason), I would never expect `.GetTypeInfo()` to return `null` either. The type might fail to load in some way, but then you'd expect an exception, not `null`.

Comment: What would you do if it did return `null` and do you need to do anything specifically to achieve that? I.e. if you'd throw an exception at this point and your next line of code is calling a method on the `TypeInfo` then you're already going to be getting an exception *anyway* if it turns out to be `null`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That depends on what the eventual 'null' possibility is meant to signify, and the usage context. Sometimes there may be a safe fallback method to achieve the goal, sometimes it might be appropriate to throw a specific exception . But I would never allow my code to throw NullReferenceException, that is reserved to coding (usage) errors, and not any situation that actually *may* happen in a correctly written code.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: That is a good reasoning, thank you. I incline to also conclude that 'null' is not a valid return value from GetTypeInfo(). It would be nice to see a "proof" in form of a documentation or a statement from Microsoft, or at least be able to check all existing GetTypeInfo() implementations to see whether they fulfill this.

Comment: In MSDN docs, they usually note if the method will return null or throw exceptions, if it is not mentioned, then it is safe to assume it won't.

Comment: @Ghasan Al-Sakkaf: Yes, I realized that too. That, however, seemed to be "somehow" in conflict with the actual implementation. In addition, the fact that ReSharper marked a subsequent unchecked usage of GetTypeInfo() result as possible NullReferenceException has caused/increased my suspicion. But you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetTypeInfo() is never supposed to return null.

See the [new code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e6c2d88ef3ec9811f032087e710c3a7ef6181ffa/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Reflection/IntrospectionExtensions.cs) in .NET Core and the comment that Microsoft people who ported this code left.

Comment: In the end, I agree (actually, the new code still delegates to an implementation of IReflectableType which still leaves the question unanswered by the code itself). There is no "authoritative" answer so far, but the hints to the fact that GetTypeInfo() is never supposed to return null are in clear majority.